# PATCH API REST best naming option

Tags: rest, api

I want to add, or replace a coupon to an order via api. I thought in this two possibilities

PATCH /api/orders/{id}

```
{ "couponCode": "test"}
```

PATCH /api/orders/{id}/coupon/{couponCode}

I like the second because it's important in the application to apply a coupon code, and this url specifies it very well.

Are first and second valid possibilities following REST? The second option is valid with PUT and PATCH HTTP Methods?
Which do you think is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PATCH` method is not particularly RESTful on its own. REST is about transferring state, and `PATCH` doesn't really do that, instead it sends an instruction for an update.

So to make things RESTful what you will want to do is a `PUT` request to create and replace the state of a coupon *in full*.

With that being out of the way, this is not an endorsement against using `PATCH`, but my idea about this is that it's a good idea to:

1. Provide a proper `PUT` request to fully replace existing state.
2. With that in place add support for `PATCH` to optimize things that might be slow or clumsy.

So if you want to use `PATCH` on `/api/orders/{id}`, I would first wonder: how does the `PUT` version look like?

I don't fully understand what a `PATCH` on `/api/orders/{id}/coupon/{couponCode}` would mean. Are you updating the coupon code? It's odd because the code exists in the uri. A `DELETE` + a `PUT` makes more sense to me. Or maybe the HTTP `MOVE` method might even help? (`MOVE` also falls in the 'not RESTful camp but it's a nice optimization for `GET` + `DELETE` + `PUT).

If an order only ever has 1 coupon, I would prefer a uri structure like `/api/orders/{id}/coupon` because it's a nice singular resource and it makes total sense to replace it with `PUT` (or `PATCH` it).